# Javascript returns undefined while logs object

Tags: javascript, oop, nodes

```
selectChildByAttrbuteValue(attribute, value)
    {
        if(this.childNodes.length!=0)
        {
            for(var i=0; i<this.childNodes.length; i++)
            {
                if(typeof this.childNodes[i].attributes[attribute]!="undefined")
                {
                    if(this.childNodes[i].attributes[attribute]==value)
                    {
                        return this.childNodes[i];

                    }else
                    {
                        this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttrbuteValue(attribute, value);
                    }
                }else
                {
                    this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttrbuteValue(attribute, value);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

this code returns undefined, while when i do console.log(this.childNodes[i]); logs me the object. then i should return it.. but it returns undefined!

FULL CLASS

```
class Node
{
    constructor(nodeName, nodeType)
    {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;

        this.nodeType = nodeType;
        this.attributes = {};
        this.childNodes = [];
        this.parentNode = null;


    }

    removeChild(node)
    {
        if(node.parentNode!=null)
        {
            for(var i=0; i<this.childNodes.length; i++)
            {
                if(node == this.childNodes[i])
                {
                    this.childNodes.splice(i, 1);
                    node.parentNode = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    appendChild(child)
    {
        if(child.parentNode==null)
        {
            this.childNodes.push(child);
            child.parentNode = this;

        }else
        {
            child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
            this.childNodes.push(child);
            child.parentNode = this;

        }
    }

    selectChildByAttrbuteValue(attribute, value)
    {

        if(this.childNodes.length!=0)
        {
            for(var i=0; i<this.childNodes.length; i++)
            {
                if(typeof this.childNodes[i].attributes[attribute]!="undefined")
                {
                    if(this.childNodes[i].attributes[attribute]==value)
                    {
                        return this.childNodes[i];

                    }else
                    {
                        this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttrbuteValue(attribute, value);
                    }
                }else
                {
                    this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttrbuteValue(attribute, value);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

a full class to see ghow exactly it loops.

```
Xml_Node {
  nodeName: 'row',
  nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
  attributes: { name: 'Lee Pellion', characterID: '93746314' },
  childNodes: [],
  parentNode: 
   Xml_Node {
     nodeName: 'rowset',
     nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
     attributes: 
      { name: 'characters',
        key: 'characterID',
        columns: 'name,characterID' },
     childNodes: [ [Circular] ],
     parentNode: 
      Xml_Node {
        nodeName: 'result',
        nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
        attributes: {},
        childNodes: [Object],
        parentNode: [Object],
        innerText: '' },
     innerText: '' },
  innerText: '' }
```

Root Object

```
Xml_Node {
  nodeName: 'root',
  nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
  attributes: {},
  childNodes: 
   [ Xml_Node {
       nodeName: 'currentTime',
       nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
       attributes: {},
       childNodes: [],
       parentNode: [Circular],
       innerText: '2016-12-06 01:20:09' },
     Xml_Node {
       nodeName: 'result',
       nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
       attributes: {},
       childNodes: [Object],
       parentNode: [Circular],
       innerText: '' },
     Xml_Node {
       nodeName: 'cachedUntil',
       nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
       attributes: {},
       childNodes: [],
       parentNode: [Circular],
       innerText: '2017-01-06 01:20:09' } ],
  parentNode: null,
  innerText: '' }
```

with console log it works but then object just dissapears somewhere!

```
selectChildByAttributeValue(attribute, value) {

    if (this.childNodes.length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {

            if (typeof this.childNodes[i].attributes[attribute] != 'undefined') {
                if (this.childNodes[i].attributes[attribute] == value) {
                    console.log(this.childNodes[i]);
                    return this.childNodes[i];
                } else {
                    return this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttributeValue(attribute, value);
                }
            } else {
                return this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttributeValue(attribute, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT:

As we have talked in the comments and you have provided me with more info, I've come up with the following:

1. The function should be as followed:

   ```
   function selectChildByAttributeValue(attribute, value) {
       if (this.childNodes.length != 0) {
           for (var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
               if (typeof this.childNodes[i].attributes[attribute] != 'undefined') {
                   if (this.childNodes[i].attributes[attribute] == value) {
                       return this.childNodes[i];
                   } else {
                       return this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttributeValue(attribute, value);
                   }
               } else {
                   return this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttributeValue(attribute, value);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   With the return statements in place, so it can properly return a nested child.
2. Your main node doesn't have any children, that's why it's returning `undefined`.
   I did the following in my terminal and I got the right node back.

   ```
   const n = new Node('row', 'XML_ELEMENT');
   n.appendChild(new Node('rowset', 'XML_ELEMENT'));
   n.appendChild(new Node('rowset', 'XML_ELEMENT'));
   n.childNodes[0].attributes = {name: 'characters', key: 'characterID', columnds: 'name, characterID'};
   n.selectChildByAttributeValue('name', 'characters');
   ```

   With the following result:

   ```
   Node {
       nodeName: 'rowset',
           nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
           attributes:
       { name: 'characters',
           key: 'characterID',
           columnds: 'name, characterID' },
       childNodes: [],
           parentNode:
       Node {
           nodeName: 'row',
               nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
               attributes: {},
           childNodes: [ [Circular], [Object] ],
               parentNode: null } }
   ```

My root object (declared as `n` above) is as followed:

```
Node {
  nodeName: 'row',
  nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
  attributes: {},
  childNodes: 
   [ Node {
       nodeName: 'rowset',
       nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
       attributes: [Object],
       childNodes: [],
       parentNode: [Circular] },
     Node {
       nodeName: 'rowset',
       nodeType: 'XML_ELEMENT',
       attributes: {},
       childNodes: [],
       parentNode: [Circular] } ],
  parentNode: null }
```

#### Old Answer

Your function loops through itself to find something, but only has 1 return statement.
So when it calls itself to look into child values and it returns something, it's not stored in a variable or returned as well, so it's being voided.

You can solve this by placing `return` before the nested call.
So both `this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttrbuteValue(attribute, value);` should be `return this.childNodes[i].selectChildByAttrbuteValue(attribute, value);`.

Also, there is no default value, so if you're looking for a value, but not a single attribute holds that value, you're also getting `undefined`.

Small note: You're currently allowing the value `null` to be accepted in the `if` statement, this might be unwanted behaviour.

Comment: @CreasoiDev it look like it doesnt work either. or maybe i am doing smth wrong/. i posted full class to show what i am doing

Comment: Quick question, are you calling `selectChildByAttributeValue` or `selectChildByAttrbuteValue` (`Attribute` vs `Attrbute`)?

Comment: `getElementsByAttributeValue(attribute, value)
 {
  var element = this.Document.selectChildByAttributeValue(attribute, value);
  return element;
 }`

Comment: Can you give an example of what a `Node` object looks like? Just copy-paste the output of `JSON.stringify(nodeObject, null, 4);`

Comment: the one that i get or object in general ?

Comment: The `Node` object you're trying to get the elements from and / or testing the code on

Comment: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Looks like you're referencing the `parent` objects in your `childs` as well (circular). This could also be the reason it's not working...

Comment: i posted object which i made with console.log in the original post.

Comment: You sure it's not just returning undefined, because the first `childNodes` array is empty?

Comment: well, it should not loop untill that empty array. it stops right there. i log the object. i have a reference to in in variable. b ut when i return the variable it returns undefined.

Comment: console.log(this.childNodes[i].attributes.characterID); it logs the correct value. but wont return it. prob a problem with referencing it the correct way.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to update my answer, please look at that.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: hmm i will update my answer with scan of root object. it does have children, and it still returns undefined

Comment: this thing just makes me go crazy!

Comment: The root's childNodes don't have any attributes... Maybe that's why you can't find them? I'll also update my answer with my root object

Comment: ok after smashing my head against the wall i found the issue. it kept on looping untill the last element. so the returned value was changed all the time untill the last undefined cause there was no result coming.  Found child: root ->currentTime
Found child: root ->result
Found child: result ->rowset
Found child: rowset ->row
found match: row
Found child: root ->cachedUntil  as i can see here. after a match it did go to the next element which did overwrite the previous return.